# Code in Java to add two numbers is printing out sum backwards?

Tags: java, math

The following Java program (prints out addition problem of two given numbers) is printing the answer backwards ( for example, 563 instead of 365). How would I modify it so that it prints out the correct answer?
Note: I know that Im completing this problem in an unnecessarily complicated manner, but this is because we are only allowed to use primitive data types. 
Thankyou.

```
//getting the number from user
Scanner linput = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the first number:");
num = linput.nextInt();
System.out.println ("Enter the second number:");
num2 = linput.nextInt();
System.out.println (num);
System.out.println ("+");
System.out.println(num2);
System.out.println ("=======");
//making a copy of the input number
temp = num;
temp2 = num2;
//counting digits in the input number
while(num > 0)
{
num = num / 10;
count++;
}
while(num2 > 0)
{
num2 = num2 / 10;
count2++;
}
int answer = 0;
while(temp > 0 && temp2>0)
{

digit = temp % 10;
temp = temp / 10;
count--;
digit2 = temp2 % 10;
temp2 = temp2 / 10;
count2--;
answer = digit+digit2;
System.out.print(answer);
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of your `count` variable?

Comment: Everything with `"..."` is not of a primitive type. Are you not allowed to use indentation, too? Are you not allowed to use `+` for string concatenation or `out.printf()`, for that matter? `Scanner.nextInt()` returns an `int`, which is a primitive. Why don't you simple add the primitives `num` and `num2` then?

Comment: The constraint of only being allowed to use primitive data types doesn't necessitate the level of complexity that your implementation has.

Comment: First, none of your variables appear to be declared properly.  But more to the point, what is the requirement?  Why not just add the two numbers and print them?  Or are you supposed to emulate a human using carry and so forth?

Answer (score 0):

You problem statement is very unclear. If it's just simple addition of two numbers then you've really overcomplicated your implementation.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the first number:");
int num = input.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter the second number:");
int num2 = input.nextInt();
System.out.print(num + " + " + num2 + " = " + (num + num2));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, we need to emulate a human using a carry - can't just use the addition operator.

Comment: Ok, but your logic above is flawed, for example if you add 1234 and 1, your output will only be 5.  Also you are using the addition operator in the line `answer = digit+digit2`, so it's a bit odd.

Comment: Are you allowed to use arrays or simple object types (i.e. Strings) or do you need to strictly stick to the primitive types?

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with all comments that this is over complicated to do a sum. But the answer to the initial question why the result is printed backwards is that that you calculate the sum from right to left (units, tens, hundreds, ...) but print them left to right (default behavior of `print`)